# Sticky Header covering website section After click on Home Menu icon

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, header

Please help. I am getting an strange error in my single page website with sticky header. After clicking on home icon or after scrolling upwards to screen, my website div section is getting covered under header section. After getting ScrollTop>1 it works fine. Please help to resolve it.
Please see this link [Demo](http://goo.gl/eRSoJv)

Comment: That's because you need to take the size of the header into account when scrolling to the home location, or just add a white / invisible div that the header sits on top of to make it impossible to scroll past.

Comment: Thank you @JoshStevenson Can you help me how to add white space... Frankly speaking i am a novice regarding Jquery. Please help with coding part

Answer (score 1):

Change `<a href="#home">` to `<a href="#top">`

You have the Id of home set on the navbar not the container

Answer (score -2):

Change `<a href="#home">` to `<a href="#">` - hope it helps!

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Paulie_D But he didn't have certain reputation to comment

Comment: If you can't comment you need to avoid abusing the answer system to get round it. Earning rep isn't very hard.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Sorry, I'm only getting started with StackOverflow, just trying to make helpful contributions

Comment: @Paulie_D We try to encourage the new user to answer the question. Reputation is next

Comment: Yes but this wasn't an answer...it was a question see --- "Does it help?".

Comment: I'm doing my best... ;-)